# Change location for which gofortran

Tags: macos, command-line, high-sierra, permission

I downloaded gofortran, it is in the library `/usr/local/bin/`. I would like to use gofortran with R but whenever I run anything I get the following error: `make: /usr/local/gfortran: Permission denied`.

Since it appears that /usr/local is locked up I moved a copy of gofortran to  the desktop and added `export PATH=/Users/rehlab/Desktop/gfortran:$PATH` to the first line of my PATH.

Unfortunately `which gfortran` and `type gfortran` both still return `/usr/local/bin/gfortran`.

Comment: It's much, much better to keep all your programs in /usr/local - each time you upgrade and add other software it will go to that location. I would reinstall the app in the default location and keep this simple to get the default case solved. If you do that, you can edit the question above to remove the attempt you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up `/usr/local` is something there are nice tools to help with when it gets changed.

I would [install homebrew](https://brew.sh) since it has a `brew doctor` command that will tell you how to fix all permissions in the `/usr/local/`

Your error is spotted in the first line. If you install `gofortran` in `/usr/local/bin` then the make command is wrong trying to execute `/usr/local/gofortran` - permission denied is the same as "there is no program to run there.

Once you reinstall things - what does "run anything" look like specifically? You might need to ask a follow-on question detailing what you're trying to do in stead of how you tried to fix the error.

Comment: Considering the other questions of [Connorr.0](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/352231/connorr-0?tab=questions) I was inclined to raise the XY problem-flag. `brew doctor` doesn't really fix all permissions in /usr/local/. It tries to fix the permissions of its subfolder to keep brew working. Most permissions of the subfolders have been changed while installing brew. You may modify your answer to: Install homebrew, fix the permissions with `brew doctor` and then install gcc (which contains gfortran) and r with brew.

Comment: @klanomath thank you. I was uncertain but suspected gcc from brew had fortran juice in it. Great point - if usr local is messed up, brew might not even complete.